# Is there a way to auto place div in the right way based on size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to make an image gallery website, so i'm using Flask as backend to search images in database here is the code.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('__name__')
.....
.....

@app.route('/')
def index():
    images = Image_Table.query.all()
    return render_template("index.html", images=images)
```

***index.html***

```
{% 'extends base.html ' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for image in images %}
        <div class="gallery">
            <img class="image" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='photos/' + image.image_file) }}">
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

here are the styles ***style.css***

```
.gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-templates-column: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.gallery .image {
    width:100%;
}
```

So the way i want images to be displayed is like that
[image: The way i want images to be displayed]

*But instead i got this*

[image: Style i wanted]

In brief i want those empty space to be completed.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with flask. Assuming you're using bootstrap, you need to figure out the grid system

Comment: yes there is also  bootstrap !

Comment: On second thought, I'll add the `flask` tag back in just because you're using `jinja2` to render the template - but it's still not a flask issue; it's entirely frontend

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on which tool i can use to render the template in good way !??

Comment: As I already said - "you need to figure out the grid system"

Comment: I haven't said that bootstrap was inappropriate for this case. What you're seeing is implicit creation of rows of content.

Comment: Yeah i got it ! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not mind having image drawn columns by columns, you can use [CSS column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Multiple-column_Layout) .

Basicly your CSS can become:

```css
.gallery {
  column-width: 300px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/80">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/100">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/402">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/102">  
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/302"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/301">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/201">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/401">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/101">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/400">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/100"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/400">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/100">  
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/300"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/402">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/102">  
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/302"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/301">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/201">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/401">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/101">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/400">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/100">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/400">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/100"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/402">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/102">  
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/302"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/301">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/201">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/401">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/101">
</div>
```

You can aside use `clamp()` if you wish a bit more fluidity in calculating the column's width :

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp()
>
> The `clamp()` CSS function clamps a value between an upper and lower bound. `clamp()` enables selecting a middle value within a range of values between a defined minimum and maximum. It takes three parameters: a minimum value, a preferred value, and a maximum allowed value. The `clamp()` function can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`, `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<percentage>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is allowed.

```css
.gallery {
  column-width:300px;/* wherever clamp() is not supported */
  column-width: clamp(150px,30vw,300px);
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/80">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/100">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/402">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/102">  
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/302"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/301">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/201">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/401">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/101">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/400">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/100"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/400">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/100">  
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/300"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/402">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/102">  
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/302"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/301">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/201">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/401">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/101">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/400">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/100">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/400">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/100"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/402">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/102">  
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/302"> 
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/301">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/201">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/401">
  <img src=" https://picsum.photos/200/101">
</div>
```

Comment: Woah! thanks G-cyrillus,   .gallery {
  column-width: 300px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}  works as i wanted